# Can I call NavigationManager in a Blazor service

Tags: web, razor, dependency-injection, webserver, blazor

I am trying to create an error page service which, when called, will determine which type of exception has occurred and processes the code properly. If the exception is of type "redirect", it should send the user to a login page (for testing purposes, I'm just using the home "/" page).

I'm trying to use NavigationMangager.NavigateTo("/") but am running into a Null point exception whenever I reach that function call. I've been looking for a solution to this for a while now but everything I see is usage of NavigationManager in .razor files and I'm trying to complete this within a .cs service. Is this not possible currently or am I just doing something wrong? I've included all the relevant code from my file "ErrorProcessingService.cs" below, any help would be appreciated.

```
using ToDoList.Pages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace ToDoList.ExceptionHandler
{
    public class ErrorProcessingService
    {

        [Inject]
        protected NavigationManager NavigationManager {get; set;}

        public void processError(ErrorTypes.errorType et)
        {
            new ErrorTypes();
            switch(et)
            {
                case ErrorTypes.errorType.ignore:
                    //To Be Implemented
                    break;
                case ErrorTypes.errorType.popup:
                    //To Be Implemented
                    break;
                case ErrorTypes.errorType.redirect:
                    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a service you cannot use `[Inject]` attribute but inject dependency in constructor:

```cs
using ToDoList.Pages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace ToDoList.ExceptionHandler
{
    public class ErrorProcessingService
    {
        public ErrorProcessingService(NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
             NavigationManager = navigationManager;
        }

        protected NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; }

        public void processError(ErrorTypes.errorType et)
        {
            new ErrorTypes();
            switch(et)
            {
                case ErrorTypes.errorType.ignore:
                    //To Be Implemented
                    break;
                case ErrorTypes.errorType.popup:
                    //To Be Implemented
                    break;
                case ErrorTypes.errorType.redirect:
                    NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick! I also needed to change the service from singleton to scoped and after making that change, it worked

Comment: Can you add the code for the creation of this service? I can't figure out how to get a reference to NavigationManager when constructing this service.

Comment: @Adam it works by dependency injection. You just nee to add the service in DI : `services.AddTransient<ErrorProcessingService>()` for exemple.

Comment: Note: You must use AddTransient not AddSinglton