# How to use NavigationManager in a class outside razor page?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I got a singleton class Globals, and I like to have a static method to navigate to other pages across my app.

```
public class Globals
{
    public static async void openBlazorPage( string pageName )
    {
        await Task.Run( () => { NavigationManager.NavigateTo( pageName ); } );
    }
}
```

but I can not access NavigationManager in this class.

- how to access NavigationManager in a class outside razor page ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To access NavigationManager inside component code behind class outside of Razor page, use [Inject] attribute like below -

```
public class EmployeeEditBase : ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        public NavigationManager NavigationManager { get; set; }

}
```

Make sure to use code behind approach for components.

For using inside any service, use constructor injection. In your case you can use constructor inject too.

```
public class Globals
{
private readonly NavigationManager _navMagager;
public Globals(NavigationManager navManager)
{
  _navMagager = navManager;
}

    public static async void openBlazorPage( string pageName )
    {
        await Task.Run( () => { _navMagager .NavigateTo( pageName ); } );
    }
}
```

Hope, it'll help you. Thanks

Comment: And where does the navManager you pass to Globals' c'tor come from?

Comment: @Razzupaltuff The NavManager that gets passed into Globals is automatically populated by the framework through dependency injection. This post shows another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082293/can-i-call-navigationmanager-in-a-blazor-service. 

Here's some documentation on it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0